# Sprite thumbnails preview by seekbar with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I didn't find any implementation on thumbnails preview of sprite image like youtube. Did someone help with this issue and provide some implementation guide on Flutter.

Sources:
Sprite Image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GiriAakula/samuel-miller-task/master/openvideo.png

Working idea:`player.spriteThumbnails({ interval:1, url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GiriAakula/samuel-miller-task/master/openvideo.png', width: 160, height: 90 });`

Check once demo of thumbnails preview seeking on:
https://codepen.io/giriaakula/pen/dyNjRmW

Thanks for helping in Advance.